# Get rid of simplify page option in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

I am on Chrome 117.0.5938.60 which was updated on 11 Sep 23.

I occasionally see this *Simplify page* colored sticker

[image]

Which collapses into a page icon after a while

[image]

I am not sure if it is because of the update or me messing with some flags but **how do I get rid of it?**

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome flags, `chrome://flags/#contextual-page-actions-reader-mode` shows this menu.

[image]

**Select disabled** to get rid of it.